# Getting the current robot chat Id from webhook

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I'm developing multiple Telegram bots and have a PHP file for each bot. I want to combine the bots into one source code to reduce code redundancy and making maintenance easier. Is there a way to retrieve the receiving bot chat Id?, This would help me differentiate what updates will be processed by which bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different URL for each bots. for instance, use `https://t.me/webhook.php?bot=BotFather`, and check `$_GET['bot']` to determine which bot is.

Comment: Ok. I understand, set the webhook to pass the Bot Id. Thanks. Simpler solution. I thought I need to use the Telegram API but this solves the issue better.